# Why does Q's thenResolve method return undefined?

Tags: breeze, promise, q

Why isn't `thenResolve` working as I expect?

I have a method in a javascript module:

```
function addVisit(companyId) {
    var  newVisit;

    return getInventoryItems()
        .then(function(data) {
            newVisit = createVisit(companyId, data);
        })
        .then(function() {
            breezeVisitsManager.saveChanges();
        })
        .thenResolve(newVisit);
}
```

That is called by another module:

```
visitRepository.addVisit(self.companyId)
    .then(function(newVisit) {
        var route = self.visitRoute(newVisit.VisitId());
        router.navigate(route);
     }
```

newVisit exists at the time thenResolve is called, but it's undefined when the calling code receives it. I've played around with the [sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfromaniello/cyqU7/2/light/) and I don't understand why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newVisit` is `undefined` at the time you pass it to `.thenResolve` (immediately when addVisit is called).

```
function addVisit(companyId) {
    var  newVisit;

    return getInventoryItems()
        .then(function(data) {
            newVisit = createVisit(companyId, data);
        })
        .then(function() {
            breezeVisitsManager.saveChanges();
        })
        .then(function(){
            return newVisit;
        });
}
```

Promises don't change the language, `a.b.c()` will still call `c()` immediately no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try this later. However, the Q API documentation says about thenResolve "A sugar method, equivalent to promise.then(function () { return value; })", so isn't your answer identical to my code? And I don't get your last sentence -- assuming a, b & c are promises, a function supplied to c will not be called until a, b & c are fulfilled.

Comment: @JamieIde No - it seems you are new to Javascript. They are not literally equivalent, like in this case they are not because `newVisit` is not a value but a variable. I guess the documentation could be improved on that part. The language doesn't know if something is a promise everything in `a().b().c()` is executed immediately. However, any functions passed to a, b or c are called by code which makes promises work however they do.

Comment: On the contrary, I've been working with Javascript for more than 10 years but I'm new to promises. I tried your answer and it works, so thanks for that.